# ¿ Como puedo generar un ID automático en un campo que incremente su valor de 1 en 1? PHP, JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, jquery, funciones

He averiguado y solo encontré funciones para generar ID aleatorios, y lo que quiero es que aparezca un ID automático pero en correlativo.

[image]

en ese campo marcado necesito que al abrir el formulario aparezca un numero en correlativo que seria el ID.
por ejemplo que empiece desde: **001.**
y cuando se guarde el registro, la próxima vez que se abra el formulario se incremente 1 al valor.
que seria **002** y así sucesivamente.

no tengo nada de código acerca de alguna función para realizar eso.
si alguien me puede brindar alguna solución por favor.

Comment: Ese ID que tratas de que se incremente cada que se abre el formulario estará vinculado al registro que ese form permite hacer? o ¿cuál es la lógica que seguirá ese incremento?, lo pregunto por que por ejemplo si lo abri 10 veces sin hacer ninguna acción entonces ¿debe permitir el aumento?, por otro lado te invito a leer [ask], editar y agregar algo que hayas intentado

Comment: Creo que una de las soluciones puede ser ‘autonumber’ en la tabla de la db con eso evitas la generación del campo.

Comment: Si ya estás trabajando con base de datos lo ideal sería que consultes el último registro y a ese le sumes 1 y lo muestres en el value del input como dice @BetaM Si no como controlas el incremento de ese correlativo. Necesitas saber en qué correlativo vas para poder incrementar lo.